# The only one/ the only thing

Tags: translation

Today i wanna ask you how do the people say "***the only one***" in german? For example how would you translate the phrase "He is ***the only member*** of the team to focus on the problem."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one/thing = `der/die/das Einzige(if used as a noun)` or `der/die/das einzige [noun]` if used as an adjective.

So "He is the **only** member" means "Er ist das **einzige** Mitglied"